# Too many console.log statements decrease performance?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, debugging, performance

I am trying to understand if writing too many console.log statements will hinder the lightning component performance. In particular will it affects the loading and rendering time?

**please don't close this question if you don't know the answer or if don't know Salesforce just leave it as it is. Someone who knows the platform very well can answer.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426185/will-console-log-reduce-javascript-execution-performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPUs have a limited number of processor cycles. Using console.log will use CPU cycles. In computing, nothing is "free." The more you log, the slower your code will execute. This is also true in Apex. If you need to see the internal state of your code, set breakpoints with `debugger;` or use break points in your developer console.

Comment: Hi i have a question here, why people are urged to close the question because they dont know the answer for the question or the question is something off topic? If they dont know any solution i think better they can leave it as is so it can be answered by someone else. Kindly clarify. I saw three close votes which I am feeling as ridiculous and attitude of an insane